# Is there a way to perform partial match in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example, If a 'name' property's value is "iPhone 7" and my query term is "iPhone 8" I also want it to be matched.

```
match (n) WHERE n.name ~= $name ($name = 'iPhone 8')
```

If 'name' is 'iPhone 7', I want this returns true. Generally, if two strings largely matche, I want them to be matched:

"aabcde" matches "cdef": cde matches, but the 'contains' function won't work.

How to match at least these two examples in Cypher?  Is this possible at all?

Comment: You can use a lucene fuzzy search using APOC procedures, as shown in the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 5):

That specific example can use `STARTS WITH`. Also look at `CONTAINS`. Regular expressions will incur a performance hit.

From [WHERE Clauses](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#query-where-string):

> The STARTS WITH operator is used to perform case-sensitive matching on the start of strings.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name STARTS WITH 'Pet'
RETURN n.name, n.age
```

> The name and age for the 'Peter' node are returned because his name starts with 'Pet'.

Comment: How does 'iPhone 7' starts with 'iPhone 8'?  Because I am matching 'iPhone 7' against with "iPhone 8", or "aabcde" with 'cdef'. It's not 'iPhone' or "cde".